# Windows 7 on Bootcamp doesn't want to boot. Can't copy files from Bootcamp to Osx mavericks

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, hardware, file-recovery

I have strange problem. A few days ago a was doing some projects on windows 7 and updates appeared , when windows was installing updates I closed it down by holding power button. After that I can't access to windows(windows loading screen appears, it loads for about 20 min and after that nothing happens). When I'm trying to repair it with windows install cd it doesn't recognize any windows partition. Anyway I've got many project files on Bootcamp with are very important to me. I tried copy them on OSx but I can't. OSx see correctly Bootcamp partition but I can copy only small files like PDF 120kb. Whem I am trying to copy bin files(my project) an error appears "finder can't complete the operation because some data in ... Can't be read or written. Error code -36". I tried installing ntfs-3G but after that it unmounts Bootcamp and when I'm trying to mount it again error appears. I tried also Ubuntu live cd, with ntfs-3G. I tried ntfsfix commands, I tried mount it on Ubuntu but still same problem. I also took off disk form Mac and installed it in case. I plug it by USB to another computer but unfortunately same problems. Bootcamp can't be mounted. Linux says that I should log into windows and try chkdsk /f but like I said I just can't boot to windows. I hope you can help me, because this projects are very important :/
Btw. OSx also running very slowly now. Something happend after that restart on updates and mavericks is booting very slowly and also running slowly...

Comment: Anytime there are very important files, it is helpful to establish a monetary value in your mind before you decide which course of action to take. If you wouldn't even spend $50 to get them back, then you can rule out several options like buying software tailored to this task or getting professional help. Conversely, if you're willing to pay $1000 disconnect the drive and seek professional help immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem followed the hard drive when connected to a new computer, you have a clear case where the problem is disk based. The slowness, the error, and that it *seems to be getting worse* would make me think that you may only have a **short amount of time to finish your recovery efforts**.

Worst case, the drive itself is failing and you can only get files off while it cooperates. Best case, the file system is corrupt and once you zero the drive entirely, it will work properly. The test that determines which of the two is the case involves erasing the entire drive, so plan for the worst and hope for the best.

1. Consider stopping your recovery attempts if the data is of value such that you would pay a professional. If it is hardware, time may run out and running the drive could make things worse.
2. **Prioritize** and get the most important files off that drive entirely considering both the Mac side and the Windows side.
3. Use PC file recovery tools on the Boot Camp side, use Mac recovery tools like Data Rescue 3 on the Mac side. Also, don't overlook tools like `rsync` that can ignore errors and keep trying to copy other files after running into the initial error - 36.

Good luck. It seems like you have a good handle on various options for getting files off the drive so I wanted to offer some other options. Also, you made no mention of backups whatsoever - depending on how recent your last windows backup and last Mac backup are, you could reduce the scope of your efforts accordingly.